# Servidor NODE.JS não roda

Tags: node.js

Estou começando estudar o node agora, e já me deparo com esse problema. Segue o código:

```
var http = require('http')
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'Text/plain'})
  res.end('Sou um servidor criado pelo Node.js!')
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1')
```

Quando rodo executo "node node-server" no terminal não acontece nada. Há algum erro no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é o comportamento esperado. Para ver o servidor funcionando, abra o navegador e digite na barra de endereços `127.0.0.1:3000`.

O console apenas vai apresentar algo se for feita uma chamada de `console.log`.

```
var http = require('http')
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   console.log('requisição recebida')
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'Text/plain'})
   res.end('Sou um servidor criado pelo Node.js!')
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', () => console.log('servidor rodando'))
```